# Crash trying to migrate MySQL DB to SQL Server w/SQL Server Import Export Wizard

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to migrate a MySQL DB to SQL Server using MS's SQL Server Import Export Wizard.  It isn't going so well...  The wizard either tells me that the MySQL syntax is invalid or crashes depending on its mood.

Here is the query that it executes against MySQL before failing:
select * from "_account"

Anyway to change so either MySQL likes the quotes or the wizard doesn't use them?

Comment: did u set on the error log , u check the log ?

Comment: yes, the log complains about the sql statement above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to look at your MySql `sql_mode` settings. you can only use "" around table names if you have `ANSI_QUOTES` turned on, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You might might have more luck with a different migration tool: I've used [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-copy.html) and [DDLUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/ant/) with success.